# Trigger a LocalNotification when a Cell is grayed out

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, boolean, uilocalnotification, nstimezone

Here is a method that grays out a cell using QuartzCore, in a TableViewController....

```
- (void)grayOutCell:(CellGrayedOutTableViewCell *)cellGrayedOutCell {

if (cellGrayedOutCell) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        sightingsCell.contentView.alpha = 0.3f;
        CGRect oldFrame = cellGrayedOutCell.rssiImageView.frame;
        sightingsCell.rssiImageView.frame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y, 0, oldFrame.size.height);
        cellGrayedOutCell.isGrayedOut = YES;
    });
}
```

}

All of the above code works in the table view.

When the cell is grayed out I want a Local Notification to be triggered after waiting 5 seconds using the following code in my AppDelegate.m file:

```
NSDate *AlarmTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication;
UILocalNotification *notifyAlert = [[UILocationNotification alloc] init];
if (notifyAlert) {
notifyAlert.fireDate = AlarmTime;
notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
notifyAlarm.soundName = @"";
notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Cell Grayed Out";
[app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm;
}
```

Question:
Need help to understand how to link up the BOOL " cellGrayedOutCell.isGrayedOut = YES; " in the TableViewController file to trigger the localNotification in the AppDelegate.m file to send a local notification the user after waiting a few seconds.  How would this be accomplished? Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you want to setup the notification in the AppDelegate?

Comment: Need to understand where this should be set up. Is it better to trigger a local notification in the TableViewController.m file? Not sure, would like to understand how this should be handled. Thanks.

Comment: Setting it up in the controller will work fine in your case

Comment: Thanks p4sh4!  I added it to the TableViewController as an if statement.